# Hide toolbar and tablayout with searchview

Tags: java, android

I have the following layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">


<include
    android:id="@+id/app_toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
    app:tabMode="fixed" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout" />
```

The menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_white_24dp"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
    android:title="@string/search"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
```

and the code for the searchView:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager =
            (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
     this.searchView =
            (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    //searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
            search(query);
            return true;
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

The tablayout contains 2 tabs for different purposes.
I also have a searchview as option menu in my toolbar.
I would like the searchview to hide the toolbar as well as the tablayout when the searchview is clicked. You can have a look at the Whatsapp or Youtube search feature to understand what I mean.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: put the code. where you are enabling the search bar

Comment: Please click on this,This will help you [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41121270/hide-tablayout-bar-in-android/41215925](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41121270/hide-tablayout-bar-in-android/41215925)

Answer (score 0):

For that you can create custom search view like this.

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/searchViewLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/shadow"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ic_back"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center|start"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:gravity="center|start"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/backspase" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/search_view"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:gravity="center|start"
                android:hint="@string/search_hint"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/clearSearch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_cross" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/shadow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/topLayout"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabHost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/shadow"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/ColorWhite"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/ColorWhite"
        app:tabTextColor="#85A3B1" />

    <peacocktech.in.mybulletin.utils.NonSwipeableViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabHost" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

After That use this code for activity

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    menu.add(Menu.NONE, 1, Menu.NONE, getResources().getString(R.string.action_update)).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_search).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 1:

         // Visible Search layout (R.id.searchViewLayout)

           preferencesUtility.setString("search_open", "true");
           return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

onbackpress check searchview open or not

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (preferencesUtility.getString("search_open").equals("true")) {

        // Hide/Visibility gone Search layout (R.id.searchViewLayout)

    } else {

        finish
    }
}
```

Do not Show/Hide toolbar 
only set searchViewLayout visibility hide/shown.