# Hide Tablayout Bar in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, mobile, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have a activity with `toolbar` ,`Tablayout` , `viewpager`  with fragments 
like  that

[image]
I want to implement  `toolbar` material search  on all the fragments

like that [image]

but the problem is TAB Bar .
**I want to hide the tab bar(Call,Chat,Contact) on Search Open  and unhide it when the search close**

**How can I hide the tabbar ?**

I am using [this](https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView) library for material Search view implementation

layout code is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
   >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"

            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabGravity="center"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_dashboard" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: happy to help!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

here is your solution, I tried this in fragment.

### 1. Write two methods like below in your Main Activity which having tablayout for hiding and showing tablayout.

```
    public static void showTabLayout() {
                parentTabs.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

    public static void hideTabLayout() {
                parentTabs.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
```

### 2.Create Interface

```
 public interface FragmentLifecycle {

        public void onPauseFragment();
        public void onResumeFragment();

    }
```

### 3. Implement interface and call hide/show tab-layout methods

CameraFragment.java

```
package demo.com.demo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * Created by rucha on 24/11/16.
 */
public class CameraFragment extends Fragment implements FragmentLifecycle {

    public CameraFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = null;
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blue,
                container, false);
        setupUI(rootView);
        return rootView;
    }

    private void setupUI(View rootView) {
    }


    @Override
    public void onPauseFragment() {
        MainActivity.showTabLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResumeFragment() {
        MainActivity.hideTabLayout();
    }
}
```

I hope this is useful. Happy Coding!!

Comment: simple and owsome  but some modification needed ,onPauseFragment(), onResumeFragment()  name is little confusing , I wan to  hide the tab bar on searchview shown and on searchview close . not onResume and onPause

Comment: @kamran yes, definitely bcz i wrote this code according to my requirement.
but i felt some what similar to your situation so post it. i'm happy that's solves your problem. please post your ans so it would be helping for others too.

Comment: @ my answer is same as yours, only the method name is different

Comment: Hi @RuchaBhattJoshi, any idea how to achieve this in Kotlin? With the solution you gave, in Kotlin, `parentTabs` is null when I want to use it from the fragment. Thanks

Comment: Hii @schtipoun sorry, I'm also learning Kotlin; but not reaching on that point yet if I will get anything I'll post here mean while you can also update here if you get anything thank you.

Comment: @RuchaBhattJoshi yeah, I figured it out how to do it with Companion object and so on. I'll post the solution here later on :)

Comment: How to animate this?

Comment: White space comes when hide unhide tab. How to remove this?