# ActionBar with SearchView and tabs

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

I need to show the following `ActionBar`:

[image]

Does Android support it, or do I need to do a custom layout and set it to the ActionBar?

Comment: If you mean, is there one `View` like that you can drop into your layout out of the box, then no. It looks like a `Toolbar`, `SearchView`, and `TabLayout` in an `AppBarLayout`.

Comment: @MikeM. No, I think what you wrote is what I meant. I found how to add tabs to the action bar (`actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);`) but how do I add the SearchView?

Comment: It's not an old `ActionBar`. It's those components I listed above. The `AppBarLayout` is a vertical `LinearLayout` where you'd put a `Toolbar`, a `SearchView`, and a `TabLayout`. Tabs in `ActionBar` have been deprecated for a while now.

Comment: @MikeM. so what do I do?

Comment: Have a look at the layout in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41121270). You'd make an `AppBarLayout` kinda like that, but without the `FrameLayout`. The support library has its own `SearchView`, too, so you can just use that, in place of the custom version shown there.